# Deploy a web application on local weblogic

Tags: web-applications, weblogic

Our project currently uses a remote weblogic to deploy our code. I want to do the same in my local weblogic. How do I go about doing it. I have seen articles showing weblogic creation but not how to push a web application. I need to make changes to my code, restart the local server and see my changes.

Comment: [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html) is a better option as it has integrated WebLogic Server which can be used to deploy the app and test.

Comment: Eclipse will allow deploy to local server and run in debug if needed.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of IDE do you use? if any?  Most IDE's have the ability to have Weblogic as a server to test and deploy.  If you are not using any IDE, I do recommend Eclipse the free one or Netbeans.

If you are not using an IDE and compiling from the command line, make sure your deployed .war is all flatenned out inside Weblogic, and just compile and replace the .class files in the relevant locations inside  /WEB-INF  directories.

Comment: Have you tried this?  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html